# auto initializer typeid info

Tags: c++, c++17

As per C++17 Initializer Rule `auto x{123};` should be `int` but trying this out with different compilers in C++11/C++14 mode will show that some compilers will deduce it to an `int` while others will deduce it to

```
std::initialzer_list<int>
```

I am using C++17 just to test that

```
#include<iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()
{
    auto x{123};
    auto y={1,2};
    std::cout<<"Type is "<<typeid(x).name()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Type is "<<typeid(y).name()<<std::endl;

}
```

Output

```
Type is i
Type is St16initializer_listIiE
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

shouldn't it be showing 
Expected Output

```
Type is int
```

As it is present in the below reference code

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name returned by [std::type_info::name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is implementation defined, it's not guaranteed to return `"int"`.

> Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

On the other hand, you can get the type information at compile-time (with a non-defined class template). It depends on the compiler too but is much more clear in general. (The idea came from [Effective Modern C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491903996) (Scott Meyers) Item #4: Know how to view deduced types.)

```
template <typename>
struct TD;

int main()
{
    auto x{123};
    auto y={1,2};

    TD<decltype(x)> td1;
    TD<decltype(y)> td2;   
}
```

Then you'll get the type information from the compilation error message, such as [Clang](https://rextester.com/XLOV99329):

```
source_file.cpp:12:21: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<int>'
    TD<decltype(x)> td1;
                    ^
source_file.cpp:13:21: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<std::initializer_list<int> >'
    TD<decltype(y)> td2;
                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code `x{123}` evaluates to int, because that is what you passed it. However, with y, you've passed it a list of integers. Its deducing that its an `initializer_list` because that is the default type, used in initializer_list construction as per this example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <initializer_list>

class Test
{
public:
  Test(std::initializer_list<int> ints) {
    for (auto i : ints)
    {
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto x{ 123 };
  auto y = { 1,2 };
  std::cout << "Type is " << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Type is " << typeid(y).name() << std::endl;

  Test t{ 1, 2, 3 };

  std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: My question was basically on the difference between "i" and "int"

Comment: ah, well, thats implementation dependent. msvc returns int, and for the intializer_list it returns `class std::initializer_list<int>`. I'd say type info is safe to compare against another type info call, but not against a string (if you want your code to be portable).

Comment: @HariomSingh In that case most of your question is irrelevant and should be edited out. `int main() { std::cout << typeid(int).name() << '\n'; }` would've sufficed, no need to bring in `auto`, no need to bring in `std::initializer_list<int>`, no need to bring in C++11/C++14/C++17 differences.

Comment: That was just for reference that why I think it should be "int" ."i" refers to "int" I was not sure of it @hvd